# Simplified using statements in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019, using, idisposable

I'm using Unity 2019.2.18f and VS 2019 16.4.3 (CSC version 3.4.1-beta4-19610-02). I'm fairly new to both Unity and C#.

I wrote some code like this:

```
using (UdpClient client = new UdpClient(...)) {
    ...
}
```

VS 2019 suggested that the statement could be simplified to:

```
using UdpClient client = new UdpClient(...);
...
```

I guess that's a [C# 8.0 thing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement). However, when I do that, back in the Unity console it complains that there's missing parens in the `using` statement:

```
Assets\Scripts\NavioRemote.cs(106,19): error CS1003: Syntax error, '(' expected
Assets\Scripts\NavioRemote.cs(106,101): error CS1026: ) expected
```

VS, however, reports no errors.

I have two questions:

1. Why is Unity failing to compile this while VS thinks it's correct?
2. Is there a way to make Unity accept this syntax?

Comment: Probably because you are using a newer version of C# in VS. Unity only supports up to 7.3 language and 4.3 runtime: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CSharpCompiler.html

Comment: Remember that Unity does not support the latest version of C#/.Net Framework so there are syntactical differences and features that are not available.

Comment: Plus side: `using` is just syntactic sugar for closing resources defined in the parens, so you can still do what you want to do by declaring the UdpClient outside of a try block, and closing/disposing of that UdpClient in a finally block

Comment: Ah I didn't realize all this. Does Unity use a different compiler than the one installed with VS? Or does it use VS's compiler binary but supply some C# version option to it?

Comment: Oh I see from that Unity doc link from @ThomasCook that it uses Roslyn, not MS's compiler. Cool, thanks. Trying my best to wrap my head around what Unity's doing under the hood.

Comment: @JasonC Roslyn was made by Microsoft and is the official C# compiler.   It replaced a previous c# compiler in 2014/15.

Comment: @JasonC It took me a minute to find this.  https://medium.com/microsoft-open-source-stories/how-microsoft-rewrote-its-c-compiler-in-c-and-made-it-open-source-4ebed5646f98

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is Unity failing to compile this while VS thinks it's correct?

In each environment you are compiling using different language versions.  Unity only supports up to C# 7.3, while VS 2019 supports everything.  The language features your code uses requires C# 8.0.

In VS2019, go to the project's properties, the Build tab, where you'll see an "Advanced" button.  There's a dropdown to choose the language version.  I believe it defaults to "Latest", and you probably have C# 8 in the list.  If you change that to 7.3 or lower, you will see the same/similar behavior.

> Is there a way to make Unity accept this syntax?

No.  Unity only supports up to language version 7.3 right now.  But if you wait a few months or years, or time travel, then Unity will catch up.

Comment: Good call on configuring VS for 7.3, too. Thanks!

Comment: When I go to the project's properties (right click on Assembly-CSharp -> Properties) nothing happens, it seems that it immediately closes... any suggestion?